# Can't enter preside because of maintenance mode

Tags: html, css, coldfusion

I activated maintenance mode for my companies website using Preside.
Now I can't enter Preside anymore, it only shows me the maintenance mode.

I need your help, I'm not sure what I can do from this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

https://docs.preside.org/devguides/customerrorpages.html

see "Manually clearing maintenance mode":

> The bypass password can then be used by supplying it as a URL parameter to your site, e.g. http://www mysite com/?thepassword. From there, you should be able to login to the administrator and turn off maintenance mode.